# Validation on texboxes and pop up error messages and passing variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, dynamic

Alright so i am completely lost on how to do this.  What i need to do is validate the textbox's with regular expression for some and required field for all of them.  I have it set up so when the user clicks the button a new set of input fields show up every time, so that if they have more than one job experience they can put it in infinitely.  The code i tried won't work. Also may want to note that I have only done the address one so far due to running into this issue.  Once i figure that out i will be able to do the rest.

One main issue i'm having is i want it to validate on the button click before the next panel is shown.  But i can not pass the objects, I may be dumb but i'm not sure how to do it. Like if i were to have the objects in the ASP.net page it would be no issue but since i am creating these in the c# code i'm not sure how to do so.
Also, i need the error messages to show up in a pop-up window so that it doesn't take space up on the panel.

I know i'm asking a lot but i am really lost.

**The ASP.net code is just a button.**

**C# Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add any controls that have been previously added dynamically

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; ++i)
    {
        addcontrolsemployment(i + 1);
    }




}


private void addcontrolsemployment(int controlNumber)
    {


        var newPanel = new Panel();

        var employerLabel = new Label();
        var addressLabel = new Label();
        var phoneLabel = new Label();
        var fromDateLabel = new Label();
        var toDateLabel = new Label();
        var supervisorLabel = new Label();
        var jobTitleLabel = new Label();
        var dutiesLabel = new Label();
        var hoursLabel = new Label();
        var wageLabel = new Label();
        var leavingLabel = new Label();

        var employerTextbox = new TextBox();
        var addressTextbox = new TextBox();
        var phoneTextbox = new TextBox();
        var fromDateTextbox = new TextBox();
        var toDateTextbox = new TextBox();
        var supervisorTextbox = new TextBox();
        var jobTitleTextbox = new TextBox();
        var dutiesTextbox = new TextBox();
        var hoursTextbox = new TextBox();
        var wageTextbox = new TextBox();
        var leavingTextbox = new TextBox();




        // textbox needs a unique id to maintain state information
        employerTextbox.ID = "EmployerTextBox_" + controlNumber;
        addressTextbox.ID = "AddressTextbox_" + controlNumber;
        phoneTextbox.ID = "phoneTextbox_" + controlNumber;
        fromDateTextbox.ID = "fromDateTextbox_" + controlNumber;
        toDateTextbox.ID = "toDateTextbox_" + controlNumber;
        supervisorTextbox.ID = "supervisorTextbox_" + controlNumber;
        jobTitleTextbox.ID = "jobTitleTexbox_" + controlNumber;
        dutiesTextbox.ID = "dutiesTextbox_" + controlNumber;
        dutiesTextbox.Width = 250;
        hoursTextbox.ID = "hoursTexbox_" + controlNumber;
        wageTextbox.ID = "wageTexbox_" + controlNumber;
        leavingTextbox.ID = "leavingTexbox_" + controlNumber;
        leavingTextbox.Width = 250;
        //Label text
        employerLabel.Text = "Employer: ";
        addressLabel.Text = "Address: ";
        phoneLabel.Text = "Phone #: ";
        toDateLabel.Text = "To Date: ";
        fromDateLabel.Text = "From Date: ";
        supervisorLabel.Text = "Supervisor: ";
        jobTitleLabel.Text = "Job Title: ";
        dutiesLabel.Text = "Major Duties: ";
        hoursLabel.Text = "Hours Per Week:";
        wageLabel.Text = "Final Wage: $";
        leavingLabel.Text = "Reason for Leaving: ";

        //Regular Expression and Required field validators
        var addressRegEx = new RegularExpressionValidator();
        var addressRequired = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        addressRequired.Text = "Address is Required";
        addressRequired.ErrorMessage = " Please Enter less than 50 characters for address";
        addressRequired.ID = "addressRequired" + controlNumber; addressRequired.ControlToValidate = addressTextbox.Text;
        addressRegEx.ValidationExpression = ".{0,50}"; 
        addressRegEx.ControlToValidate = addressTextbox.Text;



        // add the label and textbox to the panel, then add the panel to the form
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='title-text'  >"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(employerLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'width='180px'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(employerTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td class='title-text' >"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(addressLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(addressTextbox); newPanel.Controls.Add(addressRegEx); newPanel.Controls.Add(addressRequired);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));

        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(phoneLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(phoneTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(fromDateLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(fromDateTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(toDateLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(toDateTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(supervisorLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(supervisorTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(jobTitleLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(jobTitleTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(dutiesLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text' colspan='2'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(dutiesTextbox);

        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(hoursLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(hoursTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(wageLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(wageTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td class='title-text'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(leavingLabel);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text' colspan='2'>"));
        newPanel.Controls.Add(leavingTextbox);
        newPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr></table>"));
        form1.Controls.Add(newPanel);

    }

    protected int TotalNumberAdded
    {
        get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Increase the number added and add the new label and textbox
        TotalNumberAdded++;
        addcontrolsemployment(TotalNumberAdded);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Please Enter good values" 
    ValidationExpression="^.....$" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Nota : Adjust your `ValidationExpression`

Comment: I can't use the asp page with a regular expression because i am creating the textboxes in the C# code and they are dynaming, meaning that their ID changes per click of the button